# Understanding the Etc/GMT time zone

Tags: java, iphone, timezone, app-store, jodatime

What is the rationale behind Apple using Etc/GMT timezone when they return the receipt from the App Store for auto-renewable subscriptions.

What exactly is the Etc/GMT time zone? Does the Java SDK understand this time zone? Or do I have to use other third-party libraries like [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)?

Comment: Do you have a reason to assume it's not just a strange way of saying UTC?

Comment: I guess so, but why are they using it? Just to make it look complex!

Comment: They're probably forced for some reason to work relative to a timezone database that organizes locales in the usual Continent/City structure and uses "Etc" as an escape for "things that don't follow that structure".

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Etc/GMT is *not* strictly the same thing as UTC or GMT.  They represent the same instant in time only when the offset is 0.  In all other cases, they are quite different.

Apple explains the designation [here](http://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-230/zic.tproj/datfiles/etcetera).

A quote directly from the link gives an example:

> We use POSIX-style signs in the Zone names and the output abbreviations,
>   even though this is the opposite of what many people expect.
>   POSIX has positive signs west of Greenwich, but many people expect
>   positive signs east of Greenwich.  For example, TZ='Etc/GMT+4' uses
>   the abbreviation "GMT+4" and corresponds to 4 hours behind UTC
>   (i.e. west of Greenwich) even though many people would expect it to
>   mean 4 hours ahead of UTC (i.e. east of Greenwich).

Comment: FYI - that's just apple's copy of the [tz database](http://iana.org/time-zones).  Those comments are [in the database itself](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/etcetera), not coming from Apple.

Answer (score 20):

## Offset versus zone

Understand:

- An [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is simply a number of hours-minutes-seconds, ahead of the baseline of UTC, or behind UTC.
- A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is *much* more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

## Positive versus negative numbering

Different protocols in various industries have varied in their numbering, with some considering offsets *ahead* of UTC to be positive numbers while others used negative. Symmetrically, some considered offsets *behind* UTC to be negative while others used positive.

In most modern protocols I’ve seen, such as the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), offsets ahead of UTC (towards the east) are positive, while offsets behind UTC (towards the west) are negative. So the offsets used by zones in the Americas have negative numbers such as `America/Los_Angeles` having an offset of `-07:00` or `-08:00` nowadays (varies during the year because of [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)).

I suggest you learn to think of this manner (right of UTC is positive, left of UTC is negative) as mainstream, and the opposite as a minor annoying variation.

Time zone names are generally in the format `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Edmonton`, `Europe/Paris`, `Africa/Tunis`, `Asia/Kolkata`, and `Pacific/Auckland`. See this [list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (may not be up-to-date). There are some exceptions. The `Etc/GMT…` names carry the opposite plus/minus convention:

- `Etc/GMT+1` = `-01:00` offset = One hour *behind* UTC
- `Etc/GMT+12` = `-12:00` offset = Twelve hours *behind* UTC

…and…

- `Etc/GMT-1` = `+01:00` offset = One hour *ahead of* UTC
- `Etc/GMT-12` = `+12:00` offset = Twelve hours *ahead of* UTC

Confusing? Welcome to the wacky world of date-time handling. It only gets weirder from here.

Key points:

- Understand the meaning and intentions of those people publishing data. Never assume the meaning of an input string.
- Use *java.time* classes only for all your date-time work. Never use the terrible legacy classes `java.util.Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and such.

Fortunately the *java.time* classes can help you through this muddle. See the [correct Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57188820/642706) using the `ZoneId` class.

## Your questions

> rationale behind Apple using Etc/GMT timezone

They mean an offset of zero, UTC itself. The string `Etc/GMT` is one canonical label for an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

The letter `Z` (pronounced “Zulu”) seen commonly at the end of date-time strings means the same thing, an offset of zero.

> What exactly is the Etc/GMT time zone?

The string `Etc/GMT` is a name for a time zone which has had only one offset-from-UTC ever, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Most other time zones such as `Europe/Berlin` or `Africa/Casablanca` have varied in their offset over history. For example, in [that `Africa/Casablanca` zone in Morocco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_Morocco), the politicians have decided last year that rather than switching an hour twice a year for standard time & DST, they will now stay permanently on DST year-round. I say “permanently” with a chuckle, as that really means “until the politicians change their mind again”. Politicians around the world have shown a penchant for redefining their time zones with surprising frequency.

> Does the Java SDK understand this time zone?

Yes. See [the Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57188820/642706) by Ole V.V.: `ZoneId.of( "Etc/GMT" )`

> Or do I have to use other third-party libraries like Joda-Time?

FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

You should be using *java.time* classes for all your date-time handling.

Answer (score 8):

`Etc/GMT` is just a standard way of saying `UTC`, `GMT`, `GMT0` or `GMT+00:00`.

The Java JDK understands all of the formats. You can easily see this in action by doing the following:

```
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Playground {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        for (String s : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

This will print out all the different `TimeZone` formats that your Java JDK can parse:

> ...
>   Etc/GMT
>   Etc/GMT+0
>   Etc/GMT-0
>   Etc/GMT0
>   Etc/Greenwich
>   Etc/UCT
>   Etc/UTC
>   Etc/Universal
>   ...

Comment: Exactly! It will say that it can parse it, but when I tried it throws ParseException. Although, I found the workaround for now.   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
  sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT"));
  try {
   System.out.println( sdf.parse("2011-09-02 10:26:35 Etc/GMT") );
  } catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();   
  }

Comment: See my answer for the correct way to interpret the timezone designator and the rationale.

Comment: This answer is Etc/Correct

Comment: This Answer is now obsolete. The `TimeZone` class is now legacy, replaced by `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset`. See JSR 310.

Answer (score 1):

When conveying a point in time across time zones it is a recommended standard to use either UTC or GMT (the two are roughly equivalent, for most purposes we don’t distinguish). It appears that Apple does exactly this.

The JDK understands `Etc/GMT` just fine.

```
    ZoneId etcGmt = ZoneId.of("Etc/GMT");
```

JDK uses the *tz database* (formerly known as the Olson database; link at the bottom). The list of time zone names in the database are in the other link at the bottom. `Etc/GMT` is listed there. You will notice that it is given as *the canonical* name for GMT (there are also some aliases, some current and some deprecated).

As an aside, my code line of course uses `ZoneId` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. This is the JDK class that you will want to use (there is also an old and poorly designed class for time zones that you don’t want to use).

I don’t think you meant to ask, but for anyone interested: JDK also understands `Etc/GMT+0`, `Etc/GMT+1`, `Etc/GMT0`, `Etc/GMT-0`, `Etc/GMT-1`, etc. (no pun intended) since they are in the database too. And it correctly handles the reversed sign mentioned in the quote in the accepted answer by David Peden.

**Links**

- [Wikipedia article: tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/tz_database)
- [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)
- [Documentation of `ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a [Java library](https://bintray.com/madhead/maven/by.dev.madhead.utils.appstore_receipts_validator:model) for App Store receipts and stop thinking about the date format.

Add the artifact ([`by.dev.madhead.utils.appstore_receipts_validator:model:2.0.0`](https://madhead.me/posts/appstore-receipts-validator-j/)).

Use any HTTP client to call the App Store and get the response back (here I use [Ktor](https://ktor.io/clients/http-client.html)):

```
suspend fun verify(receipt: String, password: String): VerifyReceiptResponse {
    val rawResponse = client.post<String> {
        url("https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt")
        contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
        accept(ContentType.Application.Json)
        body = VerifyReceiptRequest(
                receipt,
                password,
                true
        )
    }
}
```

Parse the response with Jackson:

```
val response = objectMapper.readValue(rawResponse)
```

Now you can use plain old Java API to work with the response.