# How can I parse this DateTime without losing TZ info?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have a bunch of strings that are DateTime values dumped from some database... Probably MySql. I have no control on the structure.

The strings look like this:

> 2011-05-17 00:00:00 Etc/GMT

I've found solutions that involve replacing "Etc/GMT" prior to the parse. This smells bad.

Is there a one step solution to turning this string to a DateTime without stripping out the timezone info?

Comment: Convert it to UTC then DateTime.Parse it.

Comment: >"I could mention the fruit-based supplier, in which case I might be contractually bound to do time in prison or kill myself or something." Sorry, I know English too bad to understand this. What means "fruit-based supplier"?

Comment: It comes from a DB dump, so the string is fixed.

Comment: @SargeBorsch: I've said too much already! Think of a fruit. You probably guessed it.

Comment: @spender I think it's not too much, but too little, because it's hard to understand. But it sounds interesting.

Comment: @SargeBorsch: he's essentially saying he's under an NDA and can't say who he's working for, but gives a very big hint.

Comment: @AaronH: How do you convert a string to UTC without parsing it?

Comment: @MyCodeSucks but what is the purpose of that phrase? I didn't get it completely. And what is the hint? He works for Apple, maybe? Why this may be important in the question?

Comment: It's not a big deal. The strings come from Apple. I can't change them.

Comment: `Etc/GMT` looks like some very custom time zone format. I doubt you can get Framework solution to deal with it...

Comment: Are you beholden to only MS code, or would a [noda-time](http://nodatime.org/) solution be Ok? [(also for folks wondering Where in the World Etc/GMT is)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303580/understanding-etc-gmt-timezone)

Comment: @AzZa, I don't know of any years that have 17 months, so the answer should be self-evident. I chose this particular string to eliminate that ambiguity.

Comment: @user7116: There's a thought. I'm open to any solution that actually understands the timezone rather that stripping it out. Can nodatime handle it?

Comment: I don't think `DateTime` can store the so-called `TimeZone`.

Comment: @KingKing: I don't need to store a TimeZone. I need to read it though in order to get a fixed point in time. I store all times as UTC. I don't know if I can trust my datasource to do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) contains `Etc/GMT` in its [time zone database](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime.TzdbCompiler/Data/2012d/etcetera) based on a quick look at the source.

The means by which you parse dates and times is a bit different in Noda Time than in the .Net Framework (I'm by no means an expert in Noda Time):

```
var pattern = ZonedDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture(
    @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss z",
    DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);

var result = pattern.Parse(@"2011-05-17 00:00:00 Etc/GMT");
if (result.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", result.Value);
}
```

Comment: I was almost at the same point myself after your suggestion above. That's lovely. Thanks for taking the time to figure this out.

Comment: ...however ZonedDateTimePattern is out of scope for me due to its protection level...

Comment: Weird, shows [public/public](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime/Text/ZonedDateTimePattern.cs).

Comment: I think I'll check it out from SCM. I think the nuget ver is old.

Comment: The road to timezone hell is paved with good intentions I guess :)

Comment: I feel humbled by this experience.

Comment: `ZonedDateTimePattern` is public and the nuget version is up to date.  Where is the issue?

Comment: Perhaps just missing `using NodaTime.Text;` ? Just guessing. :)

Answer (score 6):

[`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific format information. The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly.

For funky formats you can use `ParseExact`. And you also probably want to use `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal`:

```
String original = "2011-05-17 00:00:00 Etc/GMT";
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(
    original,
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'Etc/GMT'",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString()); // given my timezone: 5/16/2011 8:00:00 PM
Console.WriteLine(result.ToUniversalTime().ToString()); // 5/17/2011 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: I don't have the opportunity to manipulate this string. It's in a (really really) huge DB dump over which I have zero control of the format. I know of ParseExact. I don't know how to get it to parse the timezone info in this format.

Comment: You can parse it per normal, then play with `DateTimeOffset`. The difference (as I understand it) is the timezone offsets go between positive and negative.

Comment: @spender: Assuming all read as "Etc/GMT" that should be the equiv to UTC. So just read it in as `InvariantCulture` and all should be fine. You could always specify a `DateTimeStyle` as the fourth parameter in `ParseExact` if you're _that_ worried.

Comment: If taking this approach, you should probably never let it use your local time zone. You can pass `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal`, or you can let it parse as "unspecified" and afterwards apply `DateTime.SpecifyKind(dt, DateTimeKind.Utc)`.

Answer (score 3):

"Etc/GMT" is a [tz aka Olson time zone specifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). These are used pretty much everywhere but Windows, as Microsoft has their own.

So, there's nothing in .NET that will help you. You'll have to go elsewhere. As user7116 mentions, [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) supports tz time zones *and* Microsoft time zones. It's an excellent library.

Annoyingly, .NET actually does not have a `DateTime` type with a time zone attached. It can attach an *offset*, which is not quite the same (a time zone can have multiple offsets depending on DST). Noda Time *does* support this and will be able to preserve the statement exactly.

Comment: And even with the link you reference it's the equiv of Utc (`+00:00`) (which `DateTime.ParseExact` can handle fine when specifying `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal`)

Comment: UTC and GMT are *not* equivalent. UTC is an atomic time, it has no offset, and GMT is a solar time. They slowly drift apart -- this is why leap seconds exist. Leap seconds are added to UTC to ensure GMT and UTC are always less than 1 second apart. This may of course be "good enough" and probably is -- no arguments there --  but still I'd never call it equivalent.

Comment: We're talking 0.9/sec accuracy delta--I _doubt_ OP needs something _that_ finite. I'm not going to argue semantics, but for most intents and purposes they're equivalent.

Comment: @CoryNelson - You are confusing GMT with UT1 and TAI.  GMT actually is defined in modern parlance as identical to UTC.  Besides, Windows doesn't ever track leap seconds anyway.

Comment: I should add, the reason GMT and UTC are not perfectly identical is that GMT *used* to have it's own legal definition.  Saying "UTC" removes any question about it.  We still say "GMT" in many places though, especially when referring to `Europe/London` when it's *not* on summer time.