# How to convert timestamp in Etc/GMT+2 timezone to unix timestamp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs

I need to convert the following datetime format:

```
Start: {
    DateTime: '2016-09-01T03:00:00.0000000',
    TimeZone: 'Etc/GMT+2'
},
```

To an unix timestamp `1472691600000`.

This conversion should work even if input timezone changes.

This is the data I get via Office365 API. In the Office365 calendar (in browser) I put my event to start at 8:00 UTC+2.

I have been trying to find solution for this one for a while, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp is a valid ISO 8601 datetime, so we can simply use the javascript's [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to parse it to an unix timestamp.

However, the timezone seems to be a POSIX timezone. And as [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21058381/2697279) states, the `Etc/GMT+2` should translate to `GMT-2` (`-0200` in ISO 8601) rather than `+2`.

If the timestamp can be changed, it means we should have a [list of all valid timestamps](http://www.iana.org/time-zones). I wrote a simple parser to get the timestamps to JS parseable format:

```
find ./* -exec grep ^Zone {} \; | awk '{print $2" "$3}' | awk -F '[ :]' '{ printf "\"%s\": \"%+03.0f%02.0f\"\n", $1, $2, $3 }'
```

This outputs the formatted timezones that we can use as JS array. This way we can convert the POSIX timezone to ISO 8601 timezone format.

The final code would be:

```
function convertToTimestamp(datetimeObject) {

    var timezones = {
        "Africa/Algiers": "+0012",
        "Atlantic/Cape_Verde": "-0134",
        "Africa/Ndjamena": "+0100",
        "Africa/Abidjan": "-0016",
        "Africa/Cairo": "+0205",
        "Africa/Accra": "-0000",
        "Africa/Bissau": "-0102",
        "Africa/Nairobi": "+0227",
        "Africa/Monrovia": "-0043",
        "Africa/Tripoli": "+0052",
        "Indian/Mauritius": "+0350",
        "Africa/Casablanca": "-0030",
        "Africa/El_Aaiun": "-0052",
        "Africa/Maputo": "+0210",
        "Africa/Windhoek": "+0108",
        "Africa/Lagos": "+0013",
        "Indian/Reunion": "+0341",
        "Indian/Mahe": "+0341",
        "Africa/Johannesburg": "+0152",
        "Africa/Khartoum": "+0210",
        "Africa/Tunis": "+0040",
        "Antarctica/Casey": "+0000",
        "Antarctica/Davis": "+0000",
        "Antarctica/Mawson": "+0000",
        "Indian/Kerguelen": "+0000",
        "Antarctica/DumontDUrville": "+0000",
        "Antarctica/Syowa": "+0000",
        "Antarctica/Troll": "+0000",
        "Antarctica/Vostok": "+0000",
        "Antarctica/Rothera": "+0000",
        "Asia/Kabul": "+0436",
        "Asia/Yerevan": "+0258",
        "Asia/Baku": "+0319",
        "Asia/Dhaka": "+0601",
        "Asia/Thimphu": "+0558",
        "Indian/Chagos": "+0449",
        "Asia/Brunei": "+0739",
        "Asia/Rangoon": "+0624",
        "Asia/Shanghai": "+0805",
        "Asia/Urumqi": "+0550",
        "Asia/Hong_Kong": "+0736",
        "Asia/Taipei": "+0806",
        "Asia/Macau": "+0734",
        "Asia/Nicosia": "+0213",
        "Asia/Tbilisi": "+0259",
        "Asia/Dili": "+0822",
        "Asia/Kolkata": "+0553",
        "Asia/Jakarta": "+0707",
        "Asia/Pontianak": "+0717",
        "Asia/Makassar": "+0757",
        "Asia/Jayapura": "+0922",
        "Asia/Tehran": "+0325",
        "Asia/Baghdad": "+0257",
        "Asia/Jerusalem": "+0220",
        "Asia/Tokyo": "+0918",
        "Asia/Amman": "+0223",
        "Asia/Almaty": "+0507",
        "Asia/Qyzylorda": "+0421",
        "Asia/Aqtobe": "+0348",
        "Asia/Aqtau": "+0321",
        "Asia/Oral": "+0325",
        "Asia/Bishkek": "+0458",
        "Asia/Seoul": "+0827",
        "Asia/Pyongyang": "+0823",
        "Asia/Beirut": "+0222",
        "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur": "+0646",
        "Asia/Kuching": "+0721",
        "Indian/Maldives": "+0454",
        "Asia/Hovd": "+0606",
        "Asia/Ulaanbaatar": "+0707",
        "Asia/Choibalsan": "+0738",
        "Asia/Kathmandu": "+0541",
        "Asia/Karachi": "+0428",
        "Asia/Gaza": "+0217",
        "Asia/Hebron": "+0220",
        "Asia/Manila": "-1556",
        "Asia/Qatar": "+0326",
        "Asia/Riyadh": "+0306",
        "Asia/Singapore": "+0655",
        "Asia/Colombo": "+0519",
        "Asia/Damascus": "+0225",
        "Asia/Dushanbe": "+0435",
        "Asia/Bangkok": "+0642",
        "Asia/Ashgabat": "+0353",
        "Asia/Dubai": "+0341",
        "Asia/Samarkand": "+0427",
        "Asia/Tashkent": "+0437",
        "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh": "+0706",
        "Australia/Darwin": "+0843",
        "Australia/Perth": "+0743",
        "Australia/Eucla": "+0835",
        "Australia/Brisbane": "+1012",
        "Australia/Lindeman": "+0955",
        "Australia/Adelaide": "+0914",
        "Australia/Hobart": "+0949",
        "Australia/Currie": "+0935",
        "Australia/Melbourne": "+0939",
        "Australia/Sydney": "+1004",
        "Australia/Broken_Hill": "+0925",
        "Australia/Lord_Howe": "+1036",
        "Antarctica/Macquarie": "+0000",
        "Indian/Christmas": "+0702",
        "Indian/Cocos": "+0627",
        "Pacific/Fiji": "+1155",
        "Pacific/Gambier": "-0859",
        "Pacific/Marquesas": "-0918",
        "Pacific/Tahiti": "-0958",
        "Pacific/Guam": "-1421",
        "Pacific/Tarawa": "+1132",
        "Pacific/Enderbury": "-1124",
        "Pacific/Kiritimati": "-1029",
        "Pacific/Majuro": "+1124",
        "Pacific/Kwajalein": "+1109",
        "Pacific/Chuuk": "+1007",
        "Pacific/Pohnpei": "+1032",
        "Pacific/Kosrae": "+1051",
        "Pacific/Nauru": "+1107",
        "Pacific/Noumea": "+1105",
        "Pacific/Auckland": "+1139",
        "Pacific/Chatham": "+1213",
        "Pacific/Rarotonga": "-1039",
        "Pacific/Niue": "-1119",
        "Pacific/Norfolk": "+1111",
        "Pacific/Palau": "+0857",
        "Pacific/Port_Moresby": "+0948",
        "Pacific/Bougainville": "+1022",
        "Pacific/Pitcairn": "-0840",
        "Pacific/Pago_Pago": "+1237",
        "Pacific/Apia": "+1233",
        "Pacific/Guadalcanal": "+1039",
        "Pacific/Fakaofo": "-1124",
        "Pacific/Tongatapu": "+1219",
        "Pacific/Funafuti": "+1156",
        "Pacific/Wake": "+1106",
        "Pacific/Efate": "+1113",
        "Pacific/Wallis": "+1215",
        "Africa/Addis_Ababa": "+0234",
        "Africa/Asmara": "+0235",
        "Africa/Bamako": "-0032",
        "Africa/Bangui": "+0114",
        "Africa/Banjul": "-0106",
        "Africa/Blantyre": "+0220",
        "Africa/Brazzaville": "+0101",
        "Africa/Bujumbura": "+0157",
        "Africa/Conakry": "-0054",
        "Africa/Dakar": "-0109",
        "Africa/Dar_es_Salaam": "+0237",
        "Africa/Djibouti": "+0252",
        "Africa/Douala": "+0038",
        "Africa/Freetown": "-0053",
        "Africa/Gaborone": "+0143",
        "Africa/Harare": "+0204",
        "Africa/Juba": "+0206",
        "Africa/Kampala": "+0209",
        "Africa/Kigali": "+0200",
        "Africa/Kinshasa": "+0101",
        "Africa/Libreville": "+0037",
        "Africa/Lome": "+0004",
        "Africa/Luanda": "+0052",
        "Africa/Lubumbashi": "+0149",
        "Africa/Lusaka": "+0153",
        "Africa/Malabo": "+0035",
        "Africa/Maseru": "+0150",
        "Africa/Mbabane": "+0204",
        "Africa/Mogadishu": "+0301",
        "Africa/Niamey": "+0008",
        "Africa/Nouakchott": "-0103",
        "Africa/Ouagadougou": "-0006",
        "Africa/Porto-Novo": "+0010",
        "Africa/Sao_Tome": "+0026",
        "Africa/Timbuktu": "-0012",
        "America/Anguilla": "-0412",
        "America/Antigua": "-0407",
        "America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia": "-0430",
        "America/Aruba": "-0440",
        "America/Cayman": "-0525",
        "America/Coral_Harbour": "-0532",
        "America/Dominica": "-0405",
        "America/Ensenada": "-0746",
        "America/Grenada": "-0407",
        "America/Guadeloupe": "-0406",
        "America/Montreal": "-0454",
        "America/Montserrat": "-0408",
        "America/Rosario": "-0402",
        "America/St_Kitts": "-0410",
        "America/St_Lucia": "-0404",
        "America/St_Thomas": "-0419",
        "America/St_Vincent": "-0404",
        "America/Tortola": "-0418",
        "Antarctica/McMurdo": "+0000",
        "Asia/Aden": "+0259",
        "Asia/Bahrain": "+0322",
        "Asia/Chongqing": "+0706",
        "Asia/Hanoi": "+0703",
        "Asia/Harbin": "+0826",
        "Asia/Kashgar": "+0503",
        "Asia/Kuwait": "+0311",
        "Asia/Muscat": "+0354",
        "Asia/Phnom_Penh": "+0659",
        "Asia/Tel_Aviv": "+0219",
        "Asia/Vientiane": "+0650",
        "Atlantic/Jan_Mayen": "-0100",
        "Atlantic/St_Helena": "-0022",
        "Europe/Belfast": "-0023",
        "Europe/Guernsey": "-0009",
        "Europe/Isle_of_Man": "-0017",
        "Europe/Jersey": "-0008",
        "Europe/Ljubljana": "+0058",
        "Europe/Sarajevo": "+0113",
        "Europe/Skopje": "+0125",
        "Europe/Tiraspol": "+0158",
        "Europe/Vaduz": "+0038",
        "Europe/Zagreb": "+0103",
        "Indian/Antananarivo": "+0310",
        "Indian/Comoro": "+0253",
        "Indian/Mayotte": "+0300",
        "Pacific/Johnston": "-1000",
        "Pacific/Midway": "-1149",
        "Pacific/Saipan": "-1417",
        "Etc/GMT": "+0000",
        "Etc/UTC": "+0000",
        "Etc/UCT": "+0000",
        "Etc/GMT-14": "+1400",
        "Etc/GMT-13": "+1300",
        "Etc/GMT-12": "+1200",
        "Etc/GMT-11": "+1100",
        "Etc/GMT-10": "+1000",
        "Etc/GMT-9": "+0900",
        "Etc/GMT-8": "+0800",
        "Etc/GMT-7": "+0700",
        "Etc/GMT-6": "+0600",
        "Etc/GMT-5": "+0500",
        "Etc/GMT-4": "+0400",
        "Etc/GMT-3": "+0300",
        "Etc/GMT-2": "+0200",
        "Etc/GMT-1": "+0100",
        "Etc/GMT+1": "-0100",
        "Etc/GMT+2": "-0200",
        "Etc/GMT+3": "-0300",
        "Etc/GMT+4": "-0400",
        "Etc/GMT+5": "-0500",
        "Etc/GMT+6": "-0600",
        "Etc/GMT+7": "-0700",
        "Etc/GMT+8": "-0800",
        "Etc/GMT+9": "-0900",
        "Etc/GMT+10": "-1000",
        "Etc/GMT+11": "-1100",
        "Etc/GMT+12": "-1200",
        "Europe/London": "-0001",
        "Europe/Dublin": "-0025",
        "WET": "+0000",
        "CET": "+0100",
        "MET": "+0100",
        "EET": "+0200",
        "Europe/Tirane": "+0119",
        "Europe/Andorra": "+0006",
        "Europe/Vienna": "+0105",
        "Europe/Minsk": "+0150",
        "Europe/Brussels": "+0017",
        "Europe/Sofia": "+0133",
        "Europe/Prague": "+0057",
        "Europe/Copenhagen": "+0050",
        "Atlantic/Faroe": "-0027",
        "America/Danmarkshavn": "-0114",
        "America/Scoresbysund": "-0127",
        "America/Godthab": "-0326",
        "America/Thule": "-0435",
        "Europe/Tallinn": "+0139",
        "Europe/Helsinki": "+0139",
        "Europe/Paris": "+0009",
        "Europe/Berlin": "+0053",
        "Europe/Gibraltar": "-0021",
        "Europe/Athens": "+0134",
        "Europe/Budapest": "+0116",
        "Atlantic/Reykjavik": "-0128",
        "Europe/Rome": "+0049",
        "Europe/Riga": "+0136",
        "Europe/Vilnius": "+0141",
        "Europe/Luxembourg": "+0024",
        "Europe/Malta": "+0058",
        "Europe/Chisinau": "+0155",
        "Europe/Monaco": "+0029",
        "Europe/Amsterdam": "+0019",
        "Europe/Oslo": "+0043",
        "Europe/Warsaw": "+0124",
        "Europe/Lisbon": "-0036",
        "Atlantic/Azores": "-0142",
        "Atlantic/Madeira": "-0107",
        "Europe/Bucharest": "+0144",
        "Europe/Kaliningrad": "+0122",
        "Europe/Moscow": "+0230",
        "Europe/Simferopol": "+0216",
        "Europe/Astrakhan": "+0312",
        "Europe/Volgograd": "+0257",
        "Europe/Kirov": "+0318",
        "Europe/Samara": "+0320",
        "Europe/Ulyanovsk": "+0313",
        "Asia/Yekaterinburg": "+0402",
        "Asia/Omsk": "+0453",
        "Asia/Barnaul": "+0535",
        "Asia/Novosibirsk": "+0531",
        "Asia/Tomsk": "+0539",
        "Asia/Novokuznetsk": "+0548",
        "Asia/Krasnoyarsk": "+0611",
        "Asia/Irkutsk": "+0657",
        "Asia/Chita": "+0733",
        "Asia/Yakutsk": "+0838",
        "Asia/Vladivostok": "+0847",
        "Asia/Khandyga": "+0902",
        "Asia/Sakhalin": "+0930",
        "Asia/Magadan": "+1003",
        "Asia/Srednekolymsk": "+1014",
        "Asia/Ust-Nera": "+0932",
        "Asia/Kamchatka": "+1034",
        "Asia/Anadyr": "+1149",
        "Europe/Belgrade": "+0122",
        "Europe/Madrid": "-0014",
        "Africa/Ceuta": "-0021",
        "Atlantic/Canary": "-0101",
        "Europe/Stockholm": "+0112",
        "Europe/Zurich": "+0034",
        "Europe/Istanbul": "+0155",
        "Europe/Kiev": "+0202",
        "Europe/Uzhgorod": "+0129",
        "Europe/Zaporozhye": "+0220",
        "Factory": "+0000",
        "EST": "-0500",
        "MST": "-0700",
        "HST": "-1000",
        "EST5EDT": "-0500",
        "CST6CDT": "-0600",
        "MST7MDT": "-0700",
        "PST8PDT": "-0800",
        "America/New_York": "-0456",
        "America/Chicago": "-0550",
        "America/North_Dakota/Center": "-0645",
        "America/North_Dakota/New_Salem": "-0645",
        "America/North_Dakota/Beulah": "-0647",
        "America/Denver": "-0659",
        "America/Los_Angeles": "-0752",
        "America/Juneau": "+1502",
        "America/Sitka": "+1458",
        "America/Metlakatla": "+1513",
        "America/Yakutat": "+1441",
        "America/Anchorage": "+1400",
        "America/Nome": "+1258",
        "America/Adak": "+1213",
        "Pacific/Honolulu": "-1031",
        "America/Phoenix": "-0728",
        "America/Boise": "-0744",
        "America/Indiana/Indianapolis": "-0544",
        "America/Indiana/Marengo": "-0545",
        "America/Indiana/Vincennes": "-0550",
        "America/Indiana/Tell_City": "-0547",
        "America/Indiana/Petersburg": "-0549",
        "America/Indiana/Knox": "-0546",
        "America/Indiana/Winamac": "-0546",
        "America/Indiana/Vevay": "-0540",
        "America/Kentucky/Louisville": "-0543",
        "America/Kentucky/Monticello": "-0539",
        "America/Detroit": "-0532",
        "America/Menominee": "-0550",
        "America/St_Johns": "-0330",
        "America/Goose_Bay": "-0401",
        "America/Halifax": "-0414",
        "America/Glace_Bay": "-0359",
        "America/Moncton": "-0419",
        "America/Blanc-Sablon": "-0348",
        "America/Toronto": "-0517",
        "America/Thunder_Bay": "-0557",
        "America/Nipigon": "-0553",
        "America/Rainy_River": "-0618",
        "America/Atikokan": "-0606",
        "America/Winnipeg": "-0628",
        "America/Regina": "-0658",
        "America/Swift_Current": "-0711",
        "America/Edmonton": "-0733",
        "America/Vancouver": "-0812",
        "America/Dawson_Creek": "-0800",
        "America/Fort_Nelson": "-0810",
        "America/Creston": "-0746",
        "America/Pangnirtung": "+0000",
        "America/Iqaluit": "+0000",
        "America/Resolute": "+0000",
        "America/Rankin_Inlet": "+0000",
        "America/Cambridge_Bay": "+0000",
        "America/Yellowknife": "+0000",
        "America/Inuvik": "+0000",
        "America/Whitehorse": "-0900",
        "America/Dawson": "-0917",
        "America/Cancun": "-0547",
        "America/Merida": "-0558",
        "America/Matamoros": "-0640",
        "America/Monterrey": "-0641",
        "America/Mexico_City": "-0636",
        "America/Ojinaga": "-0657",
        "America/Chihuahua": "-0704",
        "America/Hermosillo": "-0723",
        "America/Mazatlan": "-0705",
        "America/Bahia_Banderas": "-0701",
        "America/Tijuana": "-0748",
        "America/Nassau": "-0509",
        "America/Barbados": "-0358",
        "America/Belize": "-0552",
        "Atlantic/Bermuda": "-0419",
        "America/Costa_Rica": "-0536",
        "America/Havana": "-0529",
        "America/Santo_Domingo": "-0439",
        "America/El_Salvador": "-0556",
        "America/Guatemala": "-0602",
        "America/Port-au-Prince": "-0449",
        "America/Tegucigalpa": "-0548",
        "America/Jamaica": "-0507",
        "America/Martinique": "-0404",
        "America/Managua": "-0545",
        "America/Panama": "-0518",
        "America/Puerto_Rico": "-0424",
        "America/Miquelon": "-0344",
        "America/Grand_Turk": "-0444",
        "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires": "-0353",
        "America/Argentina/Cordoba": "-0416",
        "America/Argentina/Salta": "-0421",
        "America/Argentina/Tucuman": "-0420",
        "America/Argentina/La_Rioja": "-0427",
        "America/Argentina/San_Juan": "-0434",
        "America/Argentina/Jujuy": "-0421",
        "America/Argentina/Catamarca": "-0423",
        "America/Argentina/Mendoza": "-0435",
        "America/Argentina/San_Luis": "-0425",
        "America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos": "-0436",
        "America/Argentina/Ushuaia": "-0433",
        "America/La_Paz": "-0432",
        "America/Noronha": "-0209",
        "America/Belem": "-0313",
        "America/Santarem": "-0338",
        "America/Fortaleza": "-0234",
        "America/Recife": "-0219",
        "America/Araguaina": "-0312",
        "America/Maceio": "-0222",
        "America/Bahia": "-0234",
        "America/Sao_Paulo": "-0306",
        "America/Campo_Grande": "-0338",
        "America/Cuiaba": "-0344",
        "America/Porto_Velho": "-0415",
        "America/Boa_Vista": "-0402",
        "America/Manaus": "-0400",
        "America/Eirunepe": "-0439",
        "America/Rio_Branco": "-0431",
        "America/Santiago": "-0442",
        "Pacific/Easter": "-0717",
        "Antarctica/Palmer": "+0000",
        "America/Bogota": "-0456",
        "America/Curacao": "-0435",
        "America/Guayaquil": "-0519",
        "Pacific/Galapagos": "-0558",
        "Atlantic/Stanley": "-0351",
        "America/Cayenne": "-0329",
        "America/Guyana": "-0352",
        "America/Asuncion": "-0350",
        "America/Lima": "-0508",
        "Atlantic/South_Georgia": "-0226",
        "America/Paramaribo": "-0340",
        "America/Port_of_Spain": "-0406",
        "America/Montevideo": "-0344",
        "America/Caracas": "-0427"
    };

    var isoDateFormat = datetimeObject.Start.DateTime + timezones[datetimeObject.Start.TimeZone];
    return Date.parse(isoDateFormat);
}
```

And you can use it with:

```
var timestampObject = {
    Start: {
        DateTime: '2016-09-01T03:00:00.0000000',
        TimeZone: 'Etc/GMT+2'
    }
};
convertToTimestamp(timestampObject); // Outputs 1472706000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Unix timestamps are timezone independent, you can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062515/do-unix-timestamps-change-across-timezones).

So you really only need to parse what's inside the `DateTime` field and get your timestamp using the `.valueOf` method

```
moment("2016-09-01 03:00:00.0000000", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS").valueOf()
```

Will return `1472688000000`

Even if you'll try to get timestamp by providing a timezone you will get the same timestamp

```
moment("2016-09-01 03:00:00.0000000", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS").tz("America/New_York").valueOf()
>> 1472688000000
moment("2016-09-01 03:00:00.0000000", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS").tz("America/Los_Angeles").valueOf()
>> 1472688000000
```