# How can I get actual date in this format?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to compare the actual date to a format like this that I'm receiving from a server:
item.expires_date.slice
"2016-11-28 22:10:57 Etc/GMT"

In javascript how could this be possible? specially for the part Etc/GMT

In the case I just wanted to compare 2016-11-28
how can I achieve this:

```
 var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);

     if(item.expires_date.slice(0, 10) > today) {
 console.log("This item have expired");

     } else {

       console.log("this item has not expired" );
     }

       }
```

it does not work because it brings to item has not expired comparing dates: 
2016-11-28 - 2016-12-28
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "Etc/GMT" is the same as "GMT+00:00", you can remove it and create a `Date` object from the string:

```js
var s = "2016-11-28 22:10:57 Etc/GMT";
var d = new Date(Date.parse(s.replace("Etc/", "")));
console.log(d.toString());
```

Then you can compare `d` to the current date.

Comment: Be careful, stripping the timezone part means it will be treated as local and hence represent a different moment in time in every time zone with a different offset. Is that what is required? Or should it always be GMT?

Comment: Etc/GMT without any offset is a UTC date and should be parsed as such, the above code will fail when the locale date is different from UTC (which it normally will be). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303580/understanding-the-etc-gmt-time-zone) for more about Etc/GMT.