# Extracting timezone number using moment.js

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

My web app client receive JSON data from rest api server.

Data contains timezone string value like as "Etc/GMT-1".
For the time calculating, I need to extract timezone number (just like -1).
If I use `parseInt(timezone);`, return value is `NaN`.

I am not sure if moment.js can handle this format and extract GMT number.
I think timezone data format maybe flexible.
So, I prefer to use moment.js.

Is there any way to extract number using moment.js?

Answer (score 4):

The string `"Etc/GMT-1"` is a valid IANA time zone identifier.  You can find it [in the tzdb sources](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2017b/etcetera#L66), and in [the list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). As pointed out [in the tzdb commentary](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2017b/etcetera#L36-L42), the sign is opposite from what you might expect.  It means UTC+1, not UTC-1.

You also said:  "I think timezone data format may be flexible."  Indeed, if your data contains any tzdb zone identifiers, you should assume that *all* time zone identifiers are also valid, including the more conventional form like `"America/Los_Angeles"` or `"Asia/Shanghai"`.  Therefore, you should not try to extract anything from the string itself.

It's important to remember that while some zones have a single fixed offset, most represent a series of offsets and the transition points between them.  Therefore, you should not try to get a single offset from a time zone id without also considering a point in time.  This is also covered in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), under the topic "Time Zone != Offset".

To use these with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), you will also need the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) add-on.  For example:

```
var timeZone = 'Etc/GMT-1';  // your time zone

var m = moment.tz(timeZone);  // get the *current* time in the time zone.
// or
var m = moment.tz(input, timeZone); // get a *specific* time in the time zone.
// or
var m = someOtherMomentObject.clone().tz(timeZone); // convert to the time zone.

var n = m.utcOffset();  // 60  (minutes West of GMT at the given point in time)

var s = m.format('Z');  // "+01:00"  (offset as a string in ISO-8601 format)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also install [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/), you can get the zone's offset:

```
var offsetHours = moment.tz.zone("Etc/GMT-1").offsets[0] / 60
```

The value of `offsetHours` variable will be `-1`. Note that I had to divide by 60, because the API returns the value in minutes.

---

As Matt reminded in the comments, usually timezones have more than one valid offset, depending on the date - due to Daylight Saving Time changes or even politicians deciding to change their country's offset - so it's better to get the offset based on a specific instant, as explained in the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/offset/):

```
moment.tz.zone('Etc/GMT-1').offset(1403465838805);
```

The parameter `1403465838805` is the number of milliseconds since `1970-01-01T00:00Z`.

Specifically for `Etc/GMT` timezones, there's no difference since they have no offset variations, but for other zones, it's better to use an instant.

Comment: Careful with this approach.  For the `Etc/GMT*` zones you're fine taking the first offset.  But for other zones, the first entry is likely to be an LMT value.  Better to ask for the offset at a particular point in time, than to evaluate the offsets array.

Comment: @MattJohnson Indeed! I've added this info to the answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Etc/GMT-1 is a standard format. Apple has documentation for it: [Documentation](https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-230/zic.tproj/datfiles/etcetera)

Just FYI, As [this Stackoverflow answear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303580/understanding-the-etc-gmt-time-zone/21058381#21058381) stated the Etc/GMT-1 should translate to GMT+1. 
If your input is always gonna be Etc/GMT# you can just extract it by writing you own one-line function as such:

```
function extract(input_string){
    return input_string.substring(input_string.indexOf("Etc/GMT")+7);
}
```

Comment: Apple has a *copy* of it.  The better copy to link to is [the one on GitHub held by Paul Eggert](https://github.com/eggert/tz) (the current tzdb maintainer).The official tzdb release is [here](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).  Also, I strongly discourage extracting a value from the string, for the reasons I pointed out in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem so created an array with [ label, value ] for autocomplete. Enjoy.

```js
// npm install -S moment-timezone

import moment from 'moment-timezone'
import timezones from '<path-to-node_modules>/node_modules/moment-timezone/data/unpacked/latest.json'

// Build Timezone Array for autocomplete
const TIMEZONES = timezones.zones.map( i => {
  let abbrs = i.abbrs.filter((el, index) => i.abbrs.indexOf(el) === index)
  return { label : `${i.name.replace('_',' ')} ( ${abbrs} )`, value: i.name}
})
```

[image: Autocomplete]
[image: Data Array]