# NSString (+timezone) to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

failing to convert NSString into NSDate

> result: date = nil;

(*NOTE: date receiving from In App Purchase Receipt)

```
NSString * date_string = @"2017-09-24 11:20:21 Etc/GMT";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date_string];
NSLog(@"date %@",date);
```

Comment: "(string contains timezone)" - yet your format contains nothing for the timezone, have you looked up the documentation for date and time formats for timezone items? Is there really "Etc/" in your string? Just seems surprising.

Comment: @CRD `Etc/GMT` is a valid time zone.

Comment: @vadian - thanks, just learnt something.

Comment: All about `Etc/GMT` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303580/understanding-the-etc-gmt-time-zone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
    NSString * date_string = @"2017-09-24 11:20:21 Etc/GMT";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date_string];
    NSLog(@"date %@",date);
```

Comment: Yes you are right, its working √ thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't told the date formatter how to deal with the funny sequence of characters at the end of the date i.e. the `Etc/GMT`. You format needs a [time zone specifier](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) at the end of it. `VV` might do the trick i.e.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"];
```