# Pandas tz.convert GMT and local time does not match

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I am trying to convert UTC data to local time Mozambique. For Mozambique the local time follows GMT+2 or Africa/Maputo. However, when using `.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert(X)` where X can either be `= 'GMT+2'` or `= 'Africa/Maputo'` I get separate answers. As an example:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2019)
N = 1000
rng = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', freq='10Min', periods=N)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(N, 3), columns=['temp','depth','acceleration'], index=rng)

print(df.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Etc/GMT+2'))

print(df.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Africa/Maputo'))
```

The code that solves my problem is: `df.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Africa/Maputo')`. Therefore, I wonder if I have misunderstood the `tz_convert('Etc/GMT+2')` method, and why the two different solutions dont provide the same answers. `tz_convert('Etc/GMT-2')` solves the trick but is not intuitive, at least to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the quoted section in the accepted answer (from David Peden) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303580/understanding-the-etc-gmt-time-zone

Answer (score 0):

The time zone conversion using etcetera works in reverse, and perhaps it should be deprecated altogether, considering the following observation on its [documentation](https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-230/zic.tproj/datfiles/etcetera):

> These entries are mostly present for historical reasons, so that
> people in areas not otherwise covered by the tz files could "zic -l"
> to a time zone that was right for their area.  **These days, the
> tz files cover almost all the inhabited world, so there's little
> need now for the entries that are not on UTC.**

Your workaround is correct and the best explanation why can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57193723/5729095). Maybe stick with the `tz_convert('Africa/Maputo')`.